# Jquery function does works on first td of table, but not on clones

Tags: jquery, html-table, clone

I have a jquery function that only allows numbers in inputbox.
It works well in first row of table, but not on the cloned rows after.
Here is my js clone code, I understand that it can have to do with `clone (true, true)` but did not solve it.

```
    var $to_clone = $('.tr_clone').first().clone();
   $(document).on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $to_clone.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
    });
```

Comment: So where's this function that only allows numbers? It's not the one posted

Comment: Are you aware that [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) accepts a couple of boolean arguments? I suspect them to be important here.

Comment: What's `$to_clone`?

Comment: regarding  mark.hch question : var $to_clone = $('.tr_clone').first().clone();

Comment: the function i use is documented here: https://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/fhYAs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it yourself too. It looks like it did, indeed, pertain to the `clone(true, true)`, but I assume you didn't use it both when defining the `$to_clone` object (which is a clone of the first row) AND when creating a clone of that object to append to the table. I used the fiddle you linked to with that numeric extension, added your code, and added `true,true` as a parameter to both `clone()` calls, and it appears to have numeric only input for all copies.

https://jsfiddle.net/59wvxa7r/

Edit: Also, friendly reminder, if you reply to a question in the comments, best to tag the user you're replying to (like @mark.hch to tag me) - that way we get a message when you reply - otherwise us lazy users may never return to see your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @mark.hch. Your fiddle works fine, I integrated your modification to my full working form (https://jsfiddle.net/rdugert/2nxhdsbq/) but I still experience the  issue on 2d lines and next... Have you changed anything else in the Numerical jquery script?

Comment: @RenaudDUGERT, Nope, didn't change anything else. I think it just has to do with execution order; the numeric function was being called on the `.numeric` elements after creating the clone, so the cloned version didn't seem to be picking it up. By placing the numeric function declaration and the `$('.numeric').numeric({...})` call before the rest of the code, it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n3o88vd1/

Comment: Hey @mark.hch, thanks for this great help! everything is solved now!

Comment: @RenaudDUGERT No problem. Cheers. See ya around.